# Backreference in Awk regex

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

Is it possible to do this in Awk?:

```
echo "eoe" | sed -nr '/^(.*)o\1$/p'
```

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: [Similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2957684/1331399)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not in standard `awk` (POSIX `awk` uses POSIX EREs which don't support back references, and `\1` means the 0x1 character in awk, though [there are some ambiguities](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105)). It's possible with `busybox awk` though using:

```
busybox awk '$0 ~ "^(.*)o\\1$"'
```

(what that may or may not do (whether that `"\\1"` should match a literal `\1` or the 0x1 character or be unspecified) is [unclear in the POSIX specification](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105). In my reading it seems to imply it should match a 0x1 character, but it doesn't with `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris 11 for instance which is a certified OS (where it matches on a literal `\1` instead))

With any `awk`, for that particular regexp, you could take another approach like:

```
awk 'length % 2 && \
       substr($0, (length+1)/2, 1) == "o" && \
       substr($0, 1, (length-1)/2) == substr($0, (length+3)/2)'
```

As mentioned above POSIX EREs don't support back-references. GNU `sed` with `-r` uses EREs, but that's GNU EREs that support back-references as an extension over the standard. What that means is that

```
grep -Ex '(.*)o\1'
```

(or same with `egrep`) is not portable. However:

```
grep -x '\(.*\)o\1'
```

is POSIX and portable. POSIX BREs do support back-references, as did historical implementations of `grep`. `perl` regexps or PCREs do support back references as well so you can do:

```
perl -lne 'print if /^(.*)o\1$/'
```