# How to refer to a regex group in awk regex?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

How can I refer to a regex group in awk regex? For example, if I have a regex group `(\w)`, how can I refer to it later in the same regex like `(\w)\1`? Does awk support this feature? Below example doesn't work.

```
# In this example, I want to change aa to aaa and cc to ccc.
echo ab aa cc de mn | gawk '{print gensub(/(\w)\1/, "\\1\\1\\1", "g")}'
# The result is: ab aa cc de mn
# The expected result is: ab aaa ccc de mn
```

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361427/backreference-in-awk-regex

Comment: @Justalearner please edit your question and show us the output you were expecting. Do you only want to make the change when you have a character repeated?

Comment: @terdon the comment above the `echo` says “I want to change aa to aaa and cc to ccc” which I assume to mean that “ab”, “de”, and “mn” are supposed to be left unchanged. The question is “how can I refer to it later in the *same* regex”.

Comment: I edited the question and added the expected result.

Comment: Thank you. But as @StephenKitt pointed out, it was perfectly obvious before, I just completely failed to see it. Sorry!

Answer (score 17):

The busybox implementation of `awk` is the only one that I know that supports back-references. It does happen to also support `gawk`'s `gensub()` and `\w` extensions:

Like with `sub()` and `gsub()`, you have to use `"..."` instead of `/.../` and use `\\1` instead of `\1` (in standard `awk`, `"\1"` is the character of value 1 (`^A`), and `/\1/` is required to match that character while `"\\1"` is (well [was](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105)) un(der)specified in POSIX; also note that POSIX EREs don't have back-references, that's the one feature BREs have but not EREs).

```
$ echo ab aa cc de mn | busybox awk '{print gensub("(\\w)\\1", "\\1\\1\\1", "g")}'
ab aaa ccc de mn
```

Beware though that busybox `awk` is not *internationalised*, its `\w` only matches `a-zA-Z0-9_` regardless of the locale (same for `[[:alnum:]]`) and multi-byte characters are not supported:

```
$ echo ee éé | busybox awk '{print gensub("(\\w)\\1", "\\1\\1\\1", "g")}'
eee éé
```

With standard utilities, you'd typically use `sed` for that job:

```
sed 's/\([[:alnum:]_]\)\1/&\1/g'
```

`sed` regular expressions are *basic* regular expressions that do support back references. Some `sed` implementations support *extended* regexps with `-r` or `-E`, and POSIX will specify `-E` in the next major version of the standard, but still not back references (though capture groups for `s`'s replacement will). GNU and busybox `sed` do support back-references with `-E` but FreeBSD's `sed` doesn't.

Comment: Nice. i wasn't aware of that.  I'm not likely to use busybox awk instead of perl, but it's good to know in case I ever need it.

Comment: with perl you have to enable UTF-8 for input and output for unicode text.  e.g.  `echo ee éé | perl -CIO -pe 's/(\w)\1/$1$1$1/g'` ---> `eee ééé`

Comment: @cas, that only works for UTF-8 locale. You should rather use: `perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/(\w)\1/$1$1$1/g'`

Comment: cool.  for other readers:  to get some info on perl's -C options, run `man perlrun` and search for unicode.   for info on perl's `open` pragma, run `perldoc open`.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ echo ab aa cc de mn | perl -pe 's/(\w)\1/\1\1\1/g'
ab aaa ccc de mn
```

Sometimes you just have to accept that there are some things awk can't do, but perl can.

On the bright side, if you're skilled enough with `awk` to be using `gensub` and wanting to do back-references, you should find `perl` to be a doddle.  i.e. if you can write awk, you can write perl.

Comment: Maybe I should take a look at perl. Thanks for your answer and suggestion!

Comment: I highly recommend doing so, especially if you ever find yourself thinking "i wish awk could do this sed thing" or vice-versa.   There's a lot more to perl than just this, but very simple pipeline-filter style usage is like a combination of sed,awk,cut,grep,tr,sh and more. On steroids.

Answer (score 10):

This may be going beyond the question, but the reason why `awk` doesn't support backreferences is because `awk` has always used *real* regular expressions, ie ones that can be implemented *without recursion* by a finite-state machine. Such an implementation cannot support backreferences in any form (it can support capture groups, though the implementation is not straight-forward).

The idea with `awk` as I see it is that you're supposed to use regular expression for straight time- and memory-bounded matches, and its C-like turing-complete language for anything more complex than that.

The "regexps" from perl / pcre / etc on the contrary have grown into a compact syntax to describe recursive matching procedures which can only implemented by a turing machine. This has security implications: any search box, etc. where a untrusted user can enter such a regexp is an invitation to a denial of service attack; nobody can know how much time or memory such a match will take, and only gross measures like hard arbitrary limits on it and banning of persistent hogs are possible.

Here is an [old article](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) by Russ Cox, where all this is described more in depth.

Comment: Right. Also the general approach in awk is to introduce language constructs only for common tasks that aren't easy to do with existing language constructs (i.e. don't introduce constructs just for the sake of brevity) and this fits right in with that. The result is a simple, tiny language that you can do all text manipulation with which is well worth the tradeoff vs other much larger languages that can sometimes accomplish some tasks more briefly than awk but usually are an unintelligible pile of runes!

Answer (score 1):

Not regex, but works. Will add exactly 1 extra character, if all of the characters of the word are the same:

```
echo ab aa cc de mn | \
      awk '{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        {
          char=substr($i,1,1)
          for(j=2;j<=length($i);j++)
          {
            if(substr($i,j,1)==char) y=1
          else
            y=0
            char=substr($i,j,1)
          }
          if(y) $i=$i""char
        }
        print $0
        }'

    ab aaa ccc de mn         #output
```

Comment: That changes `aba` to `abaa`. That also affects the spacing (like tabs converting to space, leading and trailing whitespace removed) in lines where there have been at least one substitution.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Updated it to deal with aba to abaa changes.I didn't deal with the space-tab conversion, or the trailing whitespace issues.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in POSIX or any other non-busybox awk that requires a loop on all unique chars in each line since backreferences are not supported within a regexp:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    old = new = $0
    while (old != "") {
        char = substr(old,1,1)
        gsub(char,"",old)
        if ( char ~ /[[:alnum:]_]/ ) {
            gsub(char char,char char char,new)
        }
    }
    print new
}

$ echo ab aa cc de mn | awk -f tst.awk
ab aaa ccc de mn
```

The above works when the target characters are not regexp metachars as in this case. If they could be RE metachars then you'd need to escape them before using them in the regexp context of the gsub()s. You could use `char"{2}"` instead of `char char` in the gsub() regexp if you prefer.

See @Stephane's answer for how to do this task with busybox awk.